# JavaScript POST Request Issue

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

So I'm creating a mobile application using Intel XDK, I am sending a JavaScript POST request of a username and password. I also did some research on the HTTP status codes and found this:

```
200 OK - Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The actual response will depend on the request method used. In a GET request, the response will contain an entity corresponding to the requested resource. In a POST request the response will contain an entity describing or containing the result of the action.

201 Created - The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created.

202 Accepted - The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
```

So I would assume that when a new user is inserted through a POST request the status would be 201. However when I had this code:

```
        XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (XMLHTTP.status == 201) {
                alert("User created.");
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }
```

It would show the "Error!" and not "User created." But when I added this on to the code:

```
        XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (XMLHTTP.status == 201 || XMLHTTP.status == 200) {
                alert("User created.");
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }
```

It showed "User created." So I was wondering how come the status is 200 even though I'm sending a POST request to insert in to a database.

Secondly, it alerts the "User created." 4 times? Is that because it is in the function onreadystatechange so it changes each time and is alerted? If so I can I make it so that it only alerts one? Should I have an if statement wrapped in a setinterval as shown below:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (XMLHTTP.status == StatusNumberHere) {
        alert("Blah");
    }
}, 10);
```

Comment: Down-voter, no doubt this is to do with the latest meta SO incident, hope it was worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few websites use those headers, your back-end probably just sends a `200` even though the request was successful in inserting data.

About your second question, the reason your alert is triggered four times is because `onreadystatechanged` is called four times, each with a different `readyState`:

1. Server connection established
2. request received
3. processing request
4. request finished and response is ready

So you probably want to add `XMLHTTP.readyState === 4` to your if statement so it in the end becomes:

```
    XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (XMLHTTP.status === 200 && XMLHTTP.readyState === 4) {
            alert("User created.");
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you've got it mixed up. It should be readyState == 200 and status == 4. Other than great answer!

Comment: @Script47 Thanks! But I don't think so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ah, well that is strange. When I used your method it alerted nothing but inserted in to the database, but when I switched it around it alerted and inserted in to database.

Comment: Nope, after some checking I ran this code                 alert(XMLHTTP.readyState); and it returned 2 then 4. So you have got it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The status returned is based on how the server decides to handle it, in most cased you will simply get a success (200), so there is no issue or abnormality with what you have done.

setInterval = hack, avoid at all costs unless implementing some actual interval function.
You can check the the readystate of the XMLHTTP request with

```
XMLHTTP.readyState == 4
```

to filter out only the completed event.

Here is a list of the ready state events:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp